# How to fix " AttributeError: 'DistributeHandler' object has no attribute 'group' "?

Tags: websocket, web2py

I followed a video by Mr Bruno Rocha [here](https://vimeo.com/38972256) to implement simple websocket, but When i run the app I get the following exception:

**AttributeError: 'DistributeHandler' object has no attribute 'group'**

The controller is very simple:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def index():
    form = SQLFORM(Post, formstyle='divs')
    if form.process().accepted:
        websocket_send('http://127.0.0.1:8888', 'hello', 'mykey', 'mygroup')
    pass
    messages = db(Post).select(orderby=~Post.created_on)
    return dict(form=form, messages=messages)
```

In the view I do the Following to get the message:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if(!$.web2py.web2py_websocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8888/realtime/mygroup', function(e){alert(e.data)}))

     alert("html5 websocket not supported by your browser, try Google Chrome");
});
```

When the user send a message the message arrives to the server (e.g I can see it) but when I reload the page the following exceptions occur, [error log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I9QnBwuWWychq0UBbwYfVDbSZxfHEXUm) , looks like the problem happens when the server send the received message to the group, Any help please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out the problem happens because of the version 3.2.1 of tornado framework but when i updated to the latest version which is 6.0.3, it works like a charm..